# Issue adding animation to programmatically created UI element

Tags: c#, uwp

My aim is to create a textBlock containing a name, after doing something with the method `GetThings()` I want an animation to play on the textBox basically moving it out of the view. as it is being animated the next textBlock is created with the next name.

But when I try and run the program I get the error:

> No installed components were detected. Cannot resolve TargetProperty
> (UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY) on
> specified object.

There is probably a better way of doing this, but I am limited in terms of my ability and would appreciate any help on the current issue.

Below is the code for the project:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    TextBlock tb = null;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> s in things)
    {
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
            TextBlock _txtBlock = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = s.Key,
                Margin = new Thickness(131, 0, 0, 0),
                FontSize = 26,
                Height = 40,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Width = 168,

            };

            innerOverlay.Children.Add(_txtBlock);
            tb = _txtBlock;
        });

        string tested = GetThings(s.Value);
        if (tested == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageDialog failedMsg = new MessageDialog("failed", "problem");
            failedMsg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Exit"));
            IUICommand command = await failedMsg.ShowAsync();

            if (command.Label.Equals("Exit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Exit();
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {

                var animation = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    EnableDependentAnimation = true,
                    To = 40,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)),

                };
                Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, tb);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

                var sb = new Storyboard();
                sb.Children.Add(animation);

                sb.Begin();
            });

            thingGroup.Add(s.Key, tested);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In order to animate the TranslateY property of a CompositeTransform in the TextBlock's RenderTransform, such a transform would have to be applied previously to the RenderTransform property. By the way, this is not WPF.

Comment: @Clemens And what would I need to do instead?

Comment: Instead of what? You would have to assign a CompositeTransform to the TextBlock's RenderTransform, which you are apparently not doing yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having questions about how to animate the transformation of the TextBlock. @Clemens is right, you will need to create a `CompositeTransform` object and assign it to the `RenderTransform` property of the TextBlock first.

I've made a simple demo here. You could refer to it and adjust it to your real scenario.

**Code:**

```
        TextBlock _txtBlock = new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Frist One",
            //Margin = new Thickness(131, 0, 0, 0),
            FontSize = 26,
            Height = 40,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Width = 168,

        };
        RootGrid.Children.Add(_txtBlock);


        //create a CompositeTransform for the TextBlock
        CompositeTransform TextBlockTransform = new CompositeTransform();
        _txtBlock.RenderTransform = TextBlockTransform;

        //Create animation to animate the CompositeTransform
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = 0;
        animation.To = 40;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
     
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _txtBlock);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        storyboard.Begin();
```

You could get more information about Transforms and Animation here: [Transforms overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/transforms), [DoubleAnimation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation?view=winrt-22621) and [CompositeTransform Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.CompositeTransform?view=winrt-22621)